# how to compare rows from current dataset with previous dataset in Palantir foundry

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way in a Foundry Code Repository to be able to find row count of the raw dataset and compare it with clean dataset? I am trying to add a data expectation as one of the health check to see if the raw dataset is less than 1% of the previous one, if it is, then abort the build.

Any help is appreciated

There was no direct health check option that I could implement for this, I was told by palantir support to try data expectation check through python transformation code. But I am not an expert in python dataframe concept.